# using pip i install packages when i try to import the packages it shows some error ImportError no module names "package name"

Tags: python

**import fibo
ImportError: No module named fibo**

fibo path location
Location: /home/mydirectory/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 1):

It is `import Fibo` not `import fibo`